# Google Actions: Invocation name is not working

Tags: actions-on-google

I created an app in Google Actions and gave the invocation name as "Dr. Agent". Now I need to change the invocation name to "Dr. ABB". I changed the name, but it is not reflecting. Could any one please help me?

Comment: Have you re-enabled testing for your action?

Answer (score 0):

Log out of the developer console. And even the chrome if you are using the same developer account. and try to log back in and change the invocation and do publish for the test deployment. It should resolve the issue. I had similar issue too.